# How to display my AngularJS correctly for GoogleBot and Optimizely?

Tags: angularjs, seo, googlebot, optimizely

I've a website called VoteCircle (www.votecircle.com), but i noted that it doesn't display well for Google Bot/Optimizely (used for A/B tests). It shows only the content that AREN'T in ng-view. All content in ng-view isn't displayed.

it was made in AngularJS and the content in ng-view isn't displayed for those bots/previews that i mentioned.

What's the best way to fix that?

Please, see attached screenshot.

Thanks.

[image: Optimizely Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty easy fix for this. In your URL bar, click on the small key and enable mixed content. The browser blocks loading mixed content in the editor by default (HTTPS and HTTP resources combined). By enabling it you can load the rest of the page in the editor.

Comment: That key isn't for that.. It's to save a password. To do that it's a shield icon, but I already did :(

Comment: That is weird. I tried it out with your page and for me it works completely fine. Have you tried with the newest Chrome? Also, have you tried without incognito mode?